# How to find a column name in all tables of MS Access database?

Tags: ms-access

I am working with a large MS Access Database with several tables. I am wondering how could I search a column from all tables in the database?

Comment: Refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405237/find-a-table-when-you-know-the-name-of-a-column/10405808#10405808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UNION query would be one way to do it.

```
SELECT FieldA from Table 1 
UNION
Select FieldA from Table 2 
UNION 
Select FieldA from Table 3
```

Save the above as a query and then you could write another query that contains the first with whatever criteria you like.

I know this seems tedious, but that's the problem with having your data spread out so much instead of pulling it into a single table. If you can provide details on exactly what you are trying to do maybe we can give a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks John. My database contains around 100 huge tables. I want to search a field called "GPS". If I do UNION query, I have to write over 100 lines. Is there any smart way to do it?

Comment: Copy and paste? Unfortunately the smart way to do it is to merge the tables. Sounds like you are stuck with a pretty undesirable structure. Another option would be to write a VBA module to loop through the tables and query each one individually.