# How can I create button to search database column names in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a button in MS Access 2013 that allows a user to search a database for a column containing input text. I was able to find the search code in this post ( [Find a table when you know the name of a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405237/find-a-table-when-you-know-the-name-of-a-column/10405808#10405808) ) but I can't figure out how to bind it to a button. Also when I run the search function from main it doesn't give any output. The only way I can get the search function to work is to hard code the search string into the function.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim inStr As String

    ListTablesWithColumnNamesContaining (InputBox("Name contains", "Search"))
End Sub

Public Sub ListTablesWithColumnNamesContaining(ByVal pText As String)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        For Each fld In tdf.Fields
            If InStr(1, fld.Name, "pText", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print tdf.Name & ":", fld.Name
            End If
        Next fld
    Next tdf
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: There are events related to the Button control. If you right click, you should see Events. There's an On Click event you can write a sub routine for or you could also call a function.

Comment: Remove the quotes surrounding *pText* here: `InStr(1, fld.Name, "pText", vbTextCompare)`  View the output in the Immediate window; go there with Ctrl+g.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a form, put a button inside it choosing button from the Design menu tab.

Then you need to double click the button, and you will open the properties window. Inside this window in the event tab, you need to double click the "on click" row and then press the ".." button on the side.

Now you should see the VBA Editor with the cursor inside this function:

```
Private function button1_onClick (....)

End Function
```

You can copy and paste your code here inside and obtain this:

```
Private function button1_onClick (....)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim pText As String

    pText = InputBox("Name contains", "Search")
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        For Each fld In tdf.Fields
            If InStr(1, fld.Name, pText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Msgbox tdf.Name & ":" & fld.Name
            End If
        Next fld
    Next tdf
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Note that, as HansUp commented, you need to remove the quotes surrounding pText. I've also put the InputBox command directly inside this function and substituted the debug.print with a  Message Box.