# To insert a range into Access database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I would like to insert a range A1:A41 into an Access table. It's showing error data type mismatch. Please suggest.

```
Sub EBD_Uploader()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim StrSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Row = 3

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\BEO.accdb;"
cn.Open strConnection
Do While Cells(Row, 1) <> ""
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(Row, 1), Cells(Row, 41))
StrSql = "INSERT INTO EDB VALUES ('" & Rng & "') "
Set rs = cn.Execute(StrSql)
    Row = Row + 1
Loop
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: in the `StrSql` statement, change `Rng` to `Rng.Value2` `Rng` refers to the Range object (in this case a single cell), and you need `.Value2` (or `.Value` or `.Text`) to get the data *inside* the cell.

Comment: StrSql = "INSERT INTO EDB VALUES ('" & Rng.Value2 & "') "
Still showing same error

Comment: you don't have a field names set, see [INSERT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) for proper syntax

Comment: So I need to mention all fields in the INSERT INTO command? There are 41 field in the table So I want to write into a small statement.

Comment: you don't need to mention *all* the fields, but definitely the field(s) you want to insert the values into. How else would SQL know where to insert the values?

Comment: You have to somehow reference all of the columns you are inserting. Either you manually type each one, or using the techniques here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405237/find-a-table-when-you-know-the-name-of-a-column/10405808#10405808 and a bit of coding you can create a loop to generate the column names in a string and insert that into your sql string.